# how to invoke SWT window from eclipse RCP application's menu

Tags: eclipse-plugin, eclipse-rcp

I am new to the eclipse RCP application development so firstly sorry for any mistake.
I am developing a small eclipse RCP application which is having one menu with sub menu, when i click on sub menu i want to open a SWT window ,how should i do this?

Comment: What sort of window to you want? Is it really SWT or do you want an Eclipse dialog or view or editor?

Answer (score 0):

SWT uses term "**Shell**" for "**Window**".

SWT hello world example is [here](http://git.eclipse.org/c/platform/eclipse.platform.swt.git/tree/examples/org.eclipse.swt.snippets/src/org/eclipse/swt/snippets/Snippet1.java).
 Also refer other SWT snippets [here](http://www.eclipse.org/swt/snippets/).